# Adding img src from Mapping Drive

Tags: html, image, path

I'm trying to make website with localhost. The problem is, I can't get the image from mapping drive.[the location of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl5U2.png)

I'm using `<img src='z://--'>` and still not working.

The reason why I'm not placing the image on `htdocs` it's because my pc memory can't handle all the image from that Z file.

Edit :

I'm temporarily using 'image' folder on my localhost, and I'm using the directory like this..

[snapshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrqB1.png)

What i want it making new src directory from data Z and not images from the localhost...

Thank you for all you're help before.

Comment: can you show to us the snippet of your program.

Comment: done, the truth is i just wan't to know how to link image from another computer so it can appear on my localhost... it is possible? not using the database of course

Comment: If you want to access the image from another computer or web address, you can simply do that with passing that image URL to src attribute of the image.

Comment: what i can't understand is what 'format' of URL for this problem... at first i'm using "file:///Z:/logo.jpg" and it's still not working...

ah i'm forgot... i'm using AMPPS for the localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the image your trying to show is from a shared folder. You can do the following:

```
<img alt="" src="file:///SERVER:/FOLDER/IMAGES/sampleimage1.png" />
```

Comment: the SERVER is the ip address... right? trying with "file:///192.168.1.4/Form Master Produk/logo.jpg"  and it's not working...